# Rearrange result of a query that use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically , I used this query to look for the column of this particular table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARTICULAR_TABLE'
```

I also used this query below to fetch specific columns for this table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARTICULAR_TABLE'
AND COLUMN_NAME in ('A','B','C','D','E')
```

Results:

```
COLUMN_NAME
A
B
C
D
E
```

The problem is the arrangement of the result. My goal is to arrange it to my desired arrangment. Just like this.

Desired Result:

```
COLUMN_NAME
B
A
C
D
E
```

My original problem was to retrieve the columns of this particular table. The result of this query should display a single column. And I was able to achieve this using the query that I used above. Now the problem is the desired arrangement of this results. I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: one way is to use `ORDER BY` with `CASE` statement. Example : `ORDER BY CASE COLUMN_NAME WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 2 ... END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OPTON 1] : use `ORDER BY` and specify the ordering you required there

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARTICULAR_TABLE'
AND COLUMN_NAME in ('A','B','C','D','E')
ORDER BY CASE COLUMN_NAME WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 2 WHEN 'C' THEN 3 END
```

[OPTION 2] : use temp table or table variable and insert the column name in the order that you required

```
declare @col table
(
    col_order   int identity(1,1),
    colname     varchar(50)
)

insert into @col (colname) values
('B') , ('A') , ('C') , ('D') , ('E')

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS S
     INNER JOIN @col C ON S.COLUMN_NAME = C.colname
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARTICULAR_TABLE'
ORDER BY C.col_order
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need. I just want to ask additional question , I am kind of confused in the 1st option. Why do I need to set every column position? Is it possible if I can set only one or two columns to their desired position? Like I just put B as 1 and A as 2 and the other will just follow since they are not included in the condition? Why does it arrange that the 'A' and 'B' goes last?

Comment: yes. you can only specify if it only affect few columns and the rest are based on the column name ordering. then it will be something like `ORDER BY CASE COLUMN_NAME WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, COLUMN_NAME`